# Why does this matrix-multiplication function produce incorrect outputs?

Tags: java, matrix-multiplication

My current implementation is as follows, taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623876/matrix-multiplication-using-arrays) and modified to use an exclusive or instead of addition as per comments here. The assumption is made (and, for the goal of this implementation, acceptable) that all input matrices will be 4x4.

```
/**
* Produces the product of two matrices, treating the first parameter as the "left" matrix.
*/
public static int[][] multiplyMatrices(int[][] a, int[][] b)
{
    int[][] resultMatrix = new int[4][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                resultMatrix[i][j] = resultMatrix[i][j] ^ multiplyPolynomials(a[i][k], b[k][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return resultMatrix;
}
```

The `multiplyPolynomials` function is as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660372/what-is-wrong-with-this-implementation-of-bitwise-multiplication).

```
/**
* Multiplies two polynomials (mod 2) represented as integers.
* The first is converted into a binary string, which is then used
* to select a number of appropriate bit shifts of the
* second, which are then added together.
*/
public static int multiplyPolynomials(int n, int m)
{
    int result = 0x00000000;
    String ns = toBitString(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < ns.length(); i++)
    {
        int bitIndex = (ns.length() - i) -1;
        if (ns.charAt(bitIndex) == '1')
        {
            int temp = m;
            temp = temp << i;
            result = result ^ temp;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

After running `multiplyMatrices`, `resultMatrix` is passed as a parameter of `reduceMatrix`, defined below, with the second parameter being given as 0x011b. (`toBitString` is simply a shortcut for `Integer.toBinaryString`.)

```
/*
* Reduces all elements of the matrix modulo a given polynomial.
* Treats the values as bit-string representations of polynomials mod 2.
* Works by XORing various left-shifts of the modulo value with the value being reduced.
* NOTE: This comment describes both reduceMatrix() and moduloReduce().
*/
public static int[][] reduceMatrix(int[][] m, int p)
{
    int[][] reducedM = new int[4][4];

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            reducedM[i][j] = moduloReduce(m[i][j], p);
        }
    }

    return reducedM;
}

public static int moduloReduce(int f, int p)
{
    String fs = toBitString(f);
    String ps = toBitString(p);
    int temp = f;
    int q = 0;
    while (toBitString(temp).length() >= ps.length())
    {
        int j = toBitString(temp).length()-1;
        int k = ps.length()-1;
        q = p << (j-k);
        temp = temp ^ q;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

This was tested using the following two matrices as input, with the values given being explicitly in hexadecimal:

```
02 03 01 01
01 02 03 01
01 01 02 03
03 01 01 02
----------
10 26 03 15
23 41 33 04
51 32 14 43
12 12 12 12
```

With those inputs, the output matrix (in hexadecimal, reduced mod 0x011b) is:

```
10 26 03 15
23 41 33 04
51 32 14 43
12 12 12 12
```

However, completing the reduction by hand produces a different result:

```
06 af 55 7c
b7 e0 4b ca
a7 35 2e a1
66 3d 06 5c
```

So clearly the program as written is not working correctly. However, the following second input matrix (using the same first matrix) returns the correct result:

```
30 ca 96 24
32 92 09 23
3f ca 43 63
7d 5a f8 96
```

The expected (and received) result for the above input is as follows:

```
74 b2 97 d8 
68 ea b9 51 
fb 39 0a 60 
a7 a9 00 1b
```

Clearly, the output of `multiplyMatrices` is not the expected result in all cases. The matrix multiplication algorithm used appears to have worked for the poster of the linked question, and I have previously verified that `multiplyPolynomials` works as expected. What is the most likely cause of the inaccurate output from `multiplyMatrices`, and why do some inputs produce the correct output anyway?

Comment: You're going to have to explicitly explain what these functions are supposed to do, particularly `multiplyPolynomials` and `moduloReduce`.

Comment: Your `multiplyPolynomials` function seems to be a long-winded reimplementation of ordinary integer multiplication. If that was supposed to be multiplication in GF(256), it doesn't look right.

Comment: Added comments explaining each method's purpose. My understanding of multiplication in GF(256) with coefficients mod 2 is that it's done with a series of left-shifts and XOR operations, and further that XOR is equivalent to addition when working with coefficients mod 2.

Comment: `+` is *not* the special kind of addition you want, though. It's ordinary integer addition, not packed polynomial addition with coefficients mod 2.

Comment: Replacing += with =a^b in both `multiplyPolynomials` and `multiplyMatrices` works for certain inputs but not for others, unfortunately. It seems to be a step in the right track, but doesn't quite get there.